# Missing argument self when scheduling method

Tags: python, schedule

I'd like to schedule a method using the schedule module but it doesn't work.

The error message is as follows:

> Warning: Missing Argument 'self'.

Here is my code:

```
def p_b(self):
    do
    print('hello')
    do
    do

schedule.every().minute.do(p_b)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()  # error comes out. 
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Always include the full traceback report. It tells us more than you think.

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, you added "self" to the method. Self represent an instance of a class that is passed automatically when you make a call, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self-in-python) fore more info.

So try to remove the self parameter and it should just work:

```
import schedule
import time

def p_b():
    print('hello')

schedule.every().minute.do(p_b)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Edit**

If you do have that method inside a class and you have the scheduler outside, you need to call it from an instance of the class e.g.:

```
import schedule
import time

class SomeClass:
    def p_b(self):
        print('hello')

if __name__=='__main__':
    some_class = SomeClass()

    schedule.every().minute.do(some_class.p_b)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you. But def p_b(self): is a function in certain class so 'self' must need for whole code. any way to use 'schedule' for a function with self in class?

Comment: See my edit, I added an example with a class as well.